# Is there any way to get border-radius to validate?

Tags: validation, css

Including the `border-radius: num1 / num2;` property gives a `/ is an incorrect operator` error.

Is there any way to get this to validate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take the '/' out. Instead of;

```
{border-radius: 1px / 2px;}
```

Do this;

```
{border-radius: 2px;}
```

That is the proper way to define border radius.

When in doubt, try http://border-radius.com/

Answer (score 1):

Are you validating against 2.1 or 3?
http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/ If you click on the More you can change the profile to CSS 3

Comment: Yes, it is validating against CSS3 and failing.